# How can I restore my Launcher icons, all of which have disappeared?

Tags: 14.04, launcher, icons

When I logon to Ubuntu as myself, none of my launcher icons are there, e.g. Firefox, Thunderbird, YouTube etc. Also, I can't do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for terminal. However, when I logon to guest session, all the launcher icons appear, except for Thunderbird, for which I can then create my existing email account and access my inbox, but of course none of my email folders are there. Also I can do <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>T</kbd> for terminal and it works.

When I switch back to my own account, then still none of the icons appear and I can't access Terminal.

Any ideas how I can retrieve them all?

Comment: your system might have gone wrong somewhere .. why not create new account and make it admin

Comment: Not certain, but it might make a difference which desktop you're using -- i.e. are you in Kubuntu, Lubuntu, Xubuntu, Cinnamon, Gnome, etc.?

Comment: Thx for these replies. However, being a non-tecchie, how do I create a new account and make it admin?! Will it help me retrieve all my emails and folders, Firefox bookmarks etc? Also, how do I find out which desktop I'm using. I use a think pad, not sure if it makes any difference.Using a spare think pad to access this forum! Thx, David.